# Posting Post of my facebook page from Android Application in background

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have already developed one news android app. Here is I want to post that particular news link in my own facebook page via some api or some other way which is available. I want to post that news of click of button. Post is any String contains links. Anyone has idea about that ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Official way to do this is

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
    .build();
```

For more information, Please visit- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/

**Or**, you can try like this

```
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
if (intent != null) {
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
     shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setPackage(application);
     shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
   startActivity(shareIntent);
} else {
    // The application does not exist
    // Open GooglePlay or use the default system picker
}
```

Comment: Where to i pass my facebook page id  ?

Comment: It will automatically redirect you to app or website and will ask you to share the post with pre-loggedin account. No need to paas any facebook credential.

Comment: If it did help, Please "accept" the answer and upvote. Thank You

Comment: I think its post on my wall. Not facebook page.

Comment: I am looking for done in background via any apis. Is this possible ?

Comment: Just go through that facebook developer link. May be you can find something there